# How to install Chromium Web Browser on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, google-chrome, chromium

I am trying to install Google Chrome,or Chromium Web Browser on Ubuntu 15.04, I tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

in Terminal,but it says:

```
E: Unable to locate package google-chrome-stable
```

So what do I do to install Chromium Web Browser on Ubuntu 15.04?

Comment: Use the Ubuntu Software Center

Comment: Do you want Chrome or Chromium?

Comment: So Google Chrome or Chromium is the goal?

Comment: ^ Is there even much of a difference @Pilot6?

Comment: There is diference.

Comment: Idk I think they are the same thing

Comment: They are not exactly same. You can google the difference easily.

Comment: What is the difference?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can install Chromium Browser by running:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Comment: I get `E: Package 'chroumium-browser' has no installation candidate`

Comment: It is preferred that you search before answering duplicates.

Comment: @johnkieran - British spelling? =)

Comment: @cchamberlain Actually no, I spelled it right in terminal, but misspelled it when I typed it out. The reason it did not install is because I had my software sources messed up.

Answer (score 2):

Don't mix chromium and chrome. What you wrote was a command to install google chrome, but it isn't available as you didn't add their **ppa** into your repository:

```
add-apt repository ppa:[chrome ppa]
```

Chromium is good and accessible from the Software Center, but i suggest you directly download the google chrome .deb from their site, it detects linux automatically and downloads the latest .deb package version, which is opened with the software center.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to Google Chrome's website and download the `DEB` version of it. Once that `DEB` file is downloaded you can simply double-click it to install it. If, for whatever reason, you want Chromium instead of Chrome, just do what Pilot6 said, which I'll put here.

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

The advantage of Chrome over Chromium is that Chrome has a few more features and (I believe) gets security updates and the like sooner.

Here's a direct download for the 64-bit `DEB` in case you have trouble finding it:
https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

Comment: This is for Chrome, not Chromium.

Comment: @Pilot6 "I am trying to install __Google Chrome__,or Chromium Web Browser on Ubuntu 15.04"

Comment: Umm excuse me,what is the difference between Chome and Chromium?

Comment: @EmilyShan Chromium is basically the open-source version of Chrome. It has the basic features, but not as many features as Google Chrome. Google Chrome is also actively updated, while Chromium usually gets these updates later on. At least, this is how I understand it.

Comment: Which did you end up installing?

Comment: @Zacharee1: How does Chrome get updated? I installed it using the `.deb` file I downloaded from the Google website, but unlike the Windows version there's no option to check for updates under `about:chrome`.

Comment: I'm fairly certain it's under the actual three line menu. Updates should happen automatically and ask you to restart Chrome when they're ready to be installed. I'm not completely sure though. @SarahofGaia

Comment: Can't see anything like that, but thanks, anyway.

Comment: It is preferred that you search before answering duplicates.

Comment: @Tim your duplicate isn't a duplicate, and this answer isn't either. That question if asking how to install Chromium from the terminal. This question is asking how to install Chromium _or Google Chrome_ in the first place. Not necessarily through the terminal.

Comment: if you have an ancient computer running 32-bit Linux then your only choice now is Chromium if you want to get updates, as Chromes has discontinued support for 32-bit Linux